# Magento 2: How can i auto update attribute value base on change of other attribute product admin?

Tags: magento2

I need to add an extra attribute in the product edit page but that attribute value auto fillup the same as SKU when updating the product name.

Please check the screenshot link: https://prnt.sc/qwuebe
Basically, I need an attribute the same as SKU which value is auto-filling base on the product name.

Any idea please share.

Comment: you are looking like SKU?

Comment: can you update your question with example, what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I added the link for reference.

Comment: I think you need to use product save before or after event and update attribute value based on your need.

Comment: no, I don't want to update on product save. I need to change this attribute value change of product name. like onchange event.

Comment: @Camit1dk Please, describe your proper requirements on a question so, it'll help you to get a proper answer as per your need.